# How to cut and paste part of a mesh to another mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

Hi im new to Blender and i want to know when im in edit mode if i can copy or cut a selections of polygons faces and paste to another mesh.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why is this so complicated?...

Answer (score 55):

You can't do it using the normal copy and paste functions, but you can do it using a few separate shortcuts/tools:

To 'cut' part of a mesh to a new object:

**1.** In edit mode, select the parts of the mesh you want to cut.

If you want to *copy* part of the mesh and not *cut* it you will need to do step '2', otherwise skip to step '3':

**2.**  Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selected faces/edges/verts.

**3.** Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Selection* from the *Separate* menu. The selected part of the mesh will now be a separate object but you will still be in edit mode of the original object.

**4.** Leave edit mode and select the new separate object (which will be on  top of the old object).

If you wish to join this into an existing mesh you can continue:

**5.** <kbd>Shift</kbd> select a different existing mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them together.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on Ray Mairlot's answer, Blender 2.7x can't merge UVs. (When merging, it simply replaces the UVs in the active selection with those in the highest priority object)

If you want to preserve the UVs:

1. Save a copy of your blend file in legacy format and open it in blender 24x.
2. Select your previously prepared objects and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and click the prompt.
3. Save your legacy blend file and "append" your merged object to your original blend file.

Comment: is this still the case, or has the UV merging been ported over to current Blender?

Comment: I currently can't test that I'm afraid.

Comment: Is this still the case in Blender 2.8?

Comment: @AaronFranke I'm unable to test at this current moment, as I'm working on correcting a frame lag issue in 2.8 caused by either a bad or missing library in Void Linux (fix: appimage download requested). I'll edit this whenever I can test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with this add-on: 
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/CutCopyPaste3D

With CTRL-insert you copy mesh data in edit mode, switch to another object and enter edit mode, and using SHIFT-insert pastes the mesh data.

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers. There isn't any reason in that

Comment: Apologies, I had two windows open, and inadvertently answered it twice.

Comment: Does this add-on still work with Blender 2.8?

Comment: The hosting site seems to be gone.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect addon, you can find the (still free) updated version, compatible with Blender 3, here: https://moth3r.gumroad.com/l/paste